What's the issue with my lottery simulator?
I want to simulate how often you'd have to play the lottery for a win:
import random

lotterylist = [random.randint(1, 49) for x in range(6)]

winning_numbers = [6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49]

counter = 0

while winning_numbers != lotterylist:
    lotterylist = [random.randint(1, 49) for x in range(6)]

    counter += 1

print("Finished! I got", counter, "tries to win.")

I ran the program for 1.5 hours and it still ran. Does it only work if the generated list has the numbers also in the exact same row so only 6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49 would work and not 49, 33, 32, 31, 26, 6? If yes, how can I fix that?

Your first problem is that occasionally your lotterylist variable could contain duplicate numbers. I'm sure that's never the case in a real lottery.

Your second problem is that the lists will only be equal if they're in the same order.

Does this answer your question? Check if two unordered lists are equal

"does it only work, if the generated list has the numbers also in the exact same row?"
Yes. winning_numbers and lotterylist are both list data type, and lists are ordered in Python.
If you don't want order to matter, you could use a set
winning_numbers = {6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49}  # set type
winning_numbers = set(6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49)  # equivalent to the above

# demonstrating "set" behavior
assert winning_numbers == {49, 26, 32, 31, 33, 6}  # True

Note that sets can't/don't contain duplicate elements. Meaning the following code would have a bug where sometimes the lotterylist has fewer than 6 numbers, if the same number was generated twice in the comprehension:
while winning_numbers != lotterylist:
    lotterylist = {random.randint(1, 49) for x in range(6)} # no good

The best (easiest and fastest-executing) approach would be using random.sample, which chooses k unique values from a population:
lotterylist = set(random.sample(range(1,50), k=6))

Why didn't it terminate?
The number of ordered 6-digit sequences of the numbers [1, 49] are 496 or 13841287201, so the chance that six numbers at random match one specific sequence is 1/13841287201. Given an event which happens with probability p, the expected number of trials E until the event occurs is simply defined as E=1/p--in this case, E = 13,841,287,201 (pretty simple). Meaning that you could expect your loop to run roughly 14 billion times before it hits the lottery.
To get an idea of about how long that could take, I timed the following code:
start_time = time.time()
counter = 13_800_000  # 13.8 million iterations
while lotterylist != [1,2,3]:
    lotterylist = [random.randint(1, 49) for x in range(6)]
    counter -= 1
    if not counter:
        break

print(time.time() - start_time)

It took 22 seconds to do this many iterations on my machine; meaning that 13.8 billion iterations would take about 6 hours, give or take an order of magnitude depending on your computer and luck.
More on probability
We are interested in the total quantity of winning possibilities, because that is what determines the expected number of trials E (times you play the lottery) before winning. We define n as the number of possibilities for each value (n=49 your case) and k as the number of samples (k=6).
If the order of the winning numbers does matter and numbers can appear more than once (as in your original code using lists), this is known as sampling with replacement, and the total number of possibilities is nk = 13,841,287,201 and E=13,841,287,201.
If order doesn't matter, and each number can only appear once, this is known as sampling without replacement, because once you select a value it can't be selected again. For sampling without replacement, the total is defined as n choose k, or C(n, k), whose formula is the binomial coefficient. Plugging in n and k gives us 13983816 combinations and therefore an expected number of trials until success of E=13,983,816
What this means is... you don't need create a simulation for the lottery at all. Probability formulas can provide you exact values, whereas simulations can only approximate. I've given you the answers--if you had a supercomputer and ran your original code a million times and took the average of all values of counter, the result would be very close to 13,841,287,201.
Just to demonstrate this, I implemented the code for six numbers where order doesn't matter:
winning_numbers = {6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49}
tot_count = 0
for i in range(5):
    counter = 0
    while winning_numbers != set(random.sample(range(1, 50), k=6)):
        counter += 1
    print(f"Attempt {i}: It took {counter} tries to win the lottery")
    tot_count += counter
print(f"It took an average of {tot_count/5} tries to win")

After 5 lotteries, I got an average of 11,752,990 tries per win--pretty close to the estimate of 13,983,816. If I kept running it, it would continue to get closer.

Thank you very much! It works now with 4 elements on the set. Do you have an idea why it still doesn't work with 5 or 6 elements? Is it just too much for my computer? No matter how long I run the program, it will never come to an end

I edited my answer to provide more info. It's not so much that it's "too much" for your computer; it's that 14 billion is a massive number of operations

There are a few issues related to both the solution and abstract logic of your code:

So only 6, 26, 31, 32, 33, 49 would work and not 49, 33, 32, 31, 26,
6?

As touched on by other answers, the line while winning_numbers != lotterylist will execute with the exact same integers in different positions. So yes, the numbers within the winning_numbers and lotterylist lists have to be in the exact order; use sets if order does not matter.

If yes, how can I fix that?

To be honest, I think that there is an issue with how you are approaching the logic of your code. In addition to your usage of the list data type, your code also runs the risk of containing duplicate numbers (as mentioned above).
I would figure out the different tasks that you want to accomplish, then splitting up your code into separate chunks to achieve said tasks (which seems to be creating two sets of 6 unique integers and checking if they are equivalent).
For starters, see:

How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?
Check if two unordered lists are equal

